# How can I using uikit to fixed the navbar on the top?

Tags: python, css, uikit, mako

I'm using the uikit css framework, I want to fixed the navbar on the top?

Comment: Please the code you have tried till now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include 'components/sticky.js' file from UIKit package and add data-uk-sticky directive to your fixed bar div.

For example:

```
<div data-uk-sticky>...</div>
```

I suggest to use it with navbar component, for example:

```
<nav id='top-bar' class="uk-navbar" data-uk-sticky>
    <a href="" class="uk-navbar-brand">...</a>
    <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">...</ul>
    <div class="uk-navbar-content">...</div>
    <div class="uk-navbar-content uk-navbar-center">...</div>
    <a href="" class="uk-navbar-toggle"></a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css file:

```
.uk-fixed-navigation {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

And add `uk-fixed-navigtion` class to your navbar.

**EDIT**

You also can use their [*sticky* component](http://getuikit.com/docs/sticky.html)